# Got Null when querying datastore by key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

I have two models, Book and Chapter, in a one-to-many relationship. I manually create the keys for both Book and Chapter. To persist, I create a book object then add an instance of chapter to it and then persist book. This works fine, as I see them in the datastore. Now when I try to fetch a chapter from the datastore by key, I get a null object.

Here is how the keys look in the datastore:

```
Under Book: name/id = 123    chapters = [Book(123)/Chapter("abc")]
Under Chapter: name/id = abc
```

I created my keys, both for creating and fetching objects, using

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Chapter.class.getSimpleName(), chapterId);
```

My fetching code is this:

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Chapter.class.getSimpleName(), chapterId);
Chapter chp = mgr.find(Chapter.class, key);//chp is always null (yes in debug mode as well)
```

UPDATE:

I try the same thing on Book and it works fine. So the problem is with Chapter. Perhaps it's because I saved Chapter through Book (but I see both in the datastore as mentioned above).

So the question is: Is there a way to retrieve chapter independently (by its key), if yes a code snippet please.

UPDATE source code:

```
@Entity
public class Book implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Chapter> Chapters = new ArrayList<Chapter>();

    public List<Chapter> getChapters() {
        return Chapters;
    }

    public void setChapters(List<Chapter> Chapters) {
        this.Chapters = Chapters;
    }

    public Book(long num, List<Chapter> Chapters) {
        super();
        Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Book.class.getSimpleName(), num);
        this.key = key;
        this.Chapters = Chapters;
    }

    public Book(long num) {
        super();
        Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Book.class.getSimpleName(), num);
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Key key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

}



@Entity
public class Chapter implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    private String content;

    public Chapter(String ChapterId, String content) {
        super();
        Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Chapter.class.getSimpleName(), ChapterId);
        this.key = key;
        this.content = content;

    }


    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Key key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void set content(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


}
```

Code for adding:

```
Book bk = new Book(num);
        Chapter chp = new Chapter(ChapterId, content);
        bk.getChapters().add(chp);
        bookDao.put(bk);

mgr.persist(bk);
```

Comment: Try just `mgr.find(Chapter.class, chapterId)`

Comment: @PeterKnego It's the first thing I tried: doesn't work either.

Comment: It seems that this question got 4 up-votes and 1 down-vote. To the guy who down-voted, if you find the question trivial, will you please provide the answer? SO recommends that you leave a comment.

Comment: the log would tell you more than you say. So you run it in "debug" mode, but keep the details to yourself

Comment: Again, if I fetch the Book, I get the chapter as well. But I can't seem to fetch the chapter by itself (i.e. using key or id)

Comment: I refer to the LOG, not the code. The LOG tells you what is happening ... likely a GET on the datastore. I see no LOG entries in your question, so just include the LOG entries for the em.find call. (PS dunno why you reply in comment to someone elses answer)

Comment: @DataNucleus I just realized I never replied to your comment. My apologies. The logs don't say anything really. After I do `Chapter chp = mgr.find(Chapter.class, key);` THEN if I try to do, say, `chp.getPageCount()` I get a null pointer exception because `chp is null`, which means `mgr.find(Chapter.class, key)` never found anything.

Answer (score 1):

I did not leave any vote, but you should provide more of the surrounding code. Things mostly look fine in the code you gave, but if you created the book/chapter in a transaction (which isn't shown), the chapter may have the book specified as a parent, and you didn't specify a parent when manually creating the chapter key.

Comment: @DataNucleus I have added the details. Whatever detail I left out I didn't think were necessary. I am desperately in need of help. I wouldn't give too little information on purpose. Thanks for leaving the node.

Comment: I don't see you calling put() on the chapter to save it to the datastore.

Comment: both get saved to the datastore, saving twice would throw an exception.

Comment: Did you try specifying the parent book entity when generating the key in your fetch code?

Comment: I have been reading through the docs. I find documents about setting an entity's key to its parent's key, but nothing about combining the two keys for a query. So far I still have what appears in the OP.

Comment: When you call createKey to fetch the chapter, use this one: createKey(Key parent, java.lang.String kind, long id)

Comment: I think we got distracted. The whole point is to be able to query the Chapter without knowing the book first. In fact, the next step is to be able to id the book from the chapter.

Comment: I think your chapter is being created with the book as the parent.  In this case, the chapter key contains the parent book's key.  So you'll need the ancestor book's key in order to generate the chapter's key.

Comment: You are probably right. But I will keep looking and let you know what I find.

Answer (score 0):

You must always include the parent entity key to retrieve the child entity.
Here is how to create a key that includes the parent:

```
Key keyBook = KeyFactory.createKey(Book.class.getSimpleName(),
    BOOK_ID); 

Key keyChapter = KeyFactory.createKey(keyBook,
    Chapter.class.getSimpleName(), CHAPTER_ID); 

Chapter chp = mgr.find(Chapter.class, keyChapter);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: My confusion is this: I see both entities in the datastore, each with its own key. I can see them. So I imagine there has to be a way to access the `Chapter` independently of a `Book`. The chapter is not an embedded entity; it exists in its own right. Perhaps there is another way to save and link them. To reply to your post alone: In python I don't remember this type of query being a problem on `ndb.Model` entities. So there must be a way to do it in Java.

Comment: In JDO you cant retrieve a child entity (by ID/NAME) without using the parent key. The child keys (id/name) are dependant to the parent. The queries by ID can only retrieve one entity, in your case if you are looking for a X chapter, this could be in N books.

Comment: you can try adding a manually created unique long/string property to your chapter, so you can make querys to obtain them.

Comment: I am using Books and Chapters because it's convenient. Image that the chapters are not numbered but rather titled so that no two chapters across all books have the same title. So let me ask this differently: is there a way to persist the chapters so that I can still get them when I query the book but also be able to query chapters independently? Notice your original suggestion was already proposed by @dragonx

Comment: ok. got it... i dont know... i will be looking for a solution.